# how to query access to select entire records given a distinct criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I want to select the entire first row of each record where a promo code is unique. I am trying to create a samples table, in this table will be one record (the first record) from each distinct promo code. I have asked all of my co-workers and they usually go though the data by hand and select one from each. the problem is that the number of promo codes grows each time and the codes change. so I want to write a query that will select the first record found to have each distinct code. so for I have something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customer.promo1 FROM Customer AS promo;

SELECT * FROM Customer, promo
WHERE Customer.promo1 = promo.promo1;
```

But this obviously give the original table. I do have a ID field called AutoID in Customer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the first Customer.AutoId associated with each Customer.Promo

```
SELECT
    c.*
FROM
    Customer  c 
    INNER JOIN 
    (

    SELECT 
        c.promo1,
        MIN(c.AutoID) AutoID
    FROM 
        Customer  c
    GROUP BY
        c.promo1) FirstCusomterWithPromo
    ON c.AutoID = FirstCusomterWithPromo.AutoID
```

Comment: does access 2007 recognize the MIN() function?

Comment: @Kyle Yep here's [the list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177686(v=office.12).aspx) of aggregate functions supported by Access SQL

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer
GROUP BY Customer.promo1
```

Comment: Access like most DBs (MySQL a notable exception) won't let you write a Group By like this. You would need to include any non-aggregated field in the group by clause. I"m also pretty sure this isn't what the OP wanted.

Comment: You are not so sure, If you decided to comment on my answer to protect yours ;)